# How to extract substring from this string?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am trying to extract the string at the end of a URL. Example:

```
C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am trying to get the `ExtractThisString.exe` from that string, however it has an unknown amount of `\`'s. I want it to basically grab the URL and list whatever is at the end of it.

Comment: Are you talking about *any* strings with \ characters in it, or is your question actually specific to Windows file paths? I'm asking because the .NET BCL has specific methods for manipulating paths, which for this purpose are preferred over generic string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the last occurence of a specified character use

```
int pos = yourString.LastIndexOf(@"\");
```

then extract the substring

```
string lastPart = yourString.Substring(pos+1);
```

**EDIT**
I am reviewing this answer after 15 months because I have really missed a key point in the question. The OP is trying to extract a filename, not just simply finding the last occurrence of a given character. So, while my answer is technically correct it is not the best one because the NET framework has a specialized class to handle file name and paths. This class is called [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) and you can find a simple and very effective way to achieve your result using [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) as explained in the answer from @Adriano.

I wish also to highlight the fact that using the methods from the Path class you have the advantage of code portability because the class handles the situation when a different operating system uses a different directory separator char.

Comment: this is the same solution as @hermiod, yet no downvote there. wtf? at least, be consistent

Comment: Edited the answer so it is possible to change the selected status

Answer (score 9):

Use helper methods of System.IO.Path class. In your case:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe");
```

Just for fun, if you have to make it by yourself you should start searching for the index of the last [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx). **If that's not the last character** in the string then you can use `String.Substring` to extract all text after that index.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var str = @"C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe";
var filename = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it once for everything...

```
public static string FileAndExtension(this string aFilePath) {
 return aFilePath.Substring(aFilePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
}
```

`"C:\\this\\that\\ExtractThisString.exe".FileAndExtension()`

OR

```
public static string EverythingAfterLast(this string aString, string aSeperator) {
 return aString.Substring(aString.LastIndexOf(aSeperator) + 1);
}
```

`"C:\\this\\that\\ExtractThisString.exe".EverythingAfterLast("\\")`

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = @"c:\this\that\extractthisstring.exe";
Console.WriteLine(path.Split('\\').Reverse().First());
```

Answer (score 0):

I find and use this elegant way using `System.IO`

`string file1 = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe");`

or if you want without extension

`string file2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe");`

or only the extension

`string ext = Path.GetExtension(@"C:\this\that\ExtractThisString.exe");`